# How to locate Static Images in Nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I created an assets folder in my NuxtJs directory and i have img folder inside it with images. Currently i am trying to load images from that directory like this

```
../../assets/img/register_bg_2.png
```

Inside Pages/auth/login/index.vue

Currently i am getting 404 not found.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put static files like images inside the `static` folder in your NuxtJS directory. If you have an image called `test.jpg` inside your static folder you should reference it as `/test.png` in your pages and components.

Reference: [Nuxt - Static directory](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static/)

Comment: Doing so will not optimize them with Webpack tho. Not sure this is the recommended way to go (for images).